# Elegant matrix rows to list?

Tags: r

Sometimes I just want to feed indices or labels into a map* type function, especially in problems where the easiest solution is to enumerate all possible combinations. So, I write an expression like this

`x = expand.grid(paste0("A", 1:10), paste0("B", 1:10))`

```
  Var1 Var2
1   A1   B1
2   A2   B1
3   A3   B1
4   A4   B1
5   A5   B1
6   A6   B1
```

Now, now I want to convert each row to a list with an ugly hack like

`data.frame(t(x))`

Or do something like this, which is annoying since the output is a nested list, and requires another `lapply` to fix.

`apply(x, 1, list)` then `lapply(.Last.value, unlist)`

There has to be a more elegant way of doing this right?

Comment: Is `split(x, row(x))` close to what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `x` is a matrix as titled for the question, I don't think it's a bad idea by doing `data.frame(t(x))`. On the other hand, if it is a data frame as generated by `expand.grid`, you can use the `transpose` function from `data.table` package, this is superior to `t(x)` because `t()` coerce the data frame to matrix which changes the underlying storage mode of the data and changes it back to a data frame which could be very inefficient, while `transpose` is designed for lists, data frames or data tables transposing as from `?transpose`:

> transpose is an efficient way to transpose lists, data frames or data tables.

Here is some benchmark about transposing a data frame:

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(data.frame(t(x)), data.table::transpose(x), split(x, 1:nrow(x)), lapply(apply(x, 1, list), unlist), times = 10)

# Unit: milliseconds
#                               expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq        max neval
#                   data.frame(t(x)) 114.061549 117.662053 121.628102 120.812289 125.132211 135.421358    10
#           data.table::transpose(x)   1.146525   1.400207   1.469908   1.467571   1.623157   1.736432    10
#                split(x, 1:nrow(x)) 160.550576 161.626339 187.385706 167.800102 179.647717 355.913319    10
#  lapply(apply(x, 1, list), unlist)   8.183313   8.379791   9.317694   8.783287   9.883049  12.345740    10
```